# Example and explanation of first-order logic theories

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was given the following definition of theories:

> A theory T is a set of closed formulas such that if T |= F then F is an element of T.

I am looking for some example theories to understand intuitively what theories are. Linear arithmetic over rationals is mentioned in my textbook but I don't really understand why that is an example theory.

Comment: First step: a closed formula is a statement without free variables, hence capable of being true or false in a model without ambiguity.  Is that notion familiar to you?

Comment: Roughly, the theory of vector spaces is the collection of all statements that are true in all vector spaces.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I think the theory of vector spaces is a bit of a complicated example, since we have to handle two sorts (the scalars and the vectors) and there are a couple natural ways to do this (incorporate the scalars into the language, or use two sorts).

Comment: It's a little odd to see $\models$ here; usually our intent is to use $\vdash$  there. (of course, $\models$ and $\vdash$ turn out to be the same relation so it's the same thing either way)

Comment: @hardmath I'm the familiar with the definition of free variables, but did you suggest that non-closed formulas can be ambiguous? Can you give me an example?

Comment: A formula like $x=y $ may be true or false, depending on the values assigned to  $x$ and $y$,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think the following explanation might be helpful:

You want to think of a theory as first and foremost a *set of statements*. So a theory is something like "$\{$John is a man, John owns a car, $2+2=5\}$" (I never said they have to be *good* statements!).

But there's two caveats here:

- We're not interested in arbitrary statements, but rather statements *of a particular form*: specifically, a theory is a set of statements *which can be expressed by a sentence of first-order logic* ("sentence" is a snappier term for "closed formula").
- We aren't interested in arbitrary sets of sentences; we're interested in sets which are *closed under deduction*. So e.g. if "$\forall x(A(x)\implies B(x))$" and "$A(c)$" are each in our theory (here $A, B$ are unary predicate symbols and $c$ is a constant symbol), then "$B(c)$" had better be in our theory. So our theories are "smart" - they know (or rather, contain) all the things they ought to. *Not all authors demand this of theories, and in fact I missed this requirement the first time I read your question.*

A useful comment on the second bullet is the following: *any* set of first-order sentences at all can be used to *generate* a theory - if $S$ is a set of sentences, we let $\langle S\rangle$ (the theory generated by $S$) be the set of sentences provable from sentences in $S$: $$\langle S\rangle=\{p: S\models p\}.$$ It is not immediately obvious that $\langle S\rangle$ is in fact a theory! However, it is, and this is a good exercise. Another good exercise is to show that for any structure $\mathcal{M}$, we have $\mathcal{M}\models S$ iff $\mathcal{M}\models \langle S\rangle$, so there's really no (semantic) difference between $S$ and $\langle S\rangle$.

What's the point of talking about theories generated by sets of statements? Well, it makes them easier to describe! Rather than listing all infinitely many sentences in a theory, I can just tell you enough sentences to *generate* the whole theory, and usually this is very easy to do. We'll see below examples of theories which are given as the theories generated by some sets of sentences.

---

My favorite example of a theory is the theory generated by the following set of sentences: $$\{\}$$ This is a very silly theory - the only things in it are the axioms of logic itself, like "$\forall x(x=x)$."

OK, what about a *non-stupid* example?

One natural example is the theory of linear order. Our language here is $\{<\}$ (where "$<$" is a binary relation symbol), and the closed formulas which make up our theory are generated by the set containing just the following three formulas:

- **Transitivity**: $\forall x\forall y\forall z(x<y \wedge y<z \implies x<z)$.
- **Asymmetry**: $\forall x\forall y(x<y\implies \neg(y<x))$.
- **Irreflexivity**: $\forall x(\neg x<x)$.

These are each closed formulas; the set of these three formulas is a theory, and this is the theory of linear order. (Sometimes the theory of linear order is developed for $\le$ in place of $<$, in which case asymmetry and irreflexivity get replaced by "$\forall x\forall y(x<y\wedge y<x\iff x=y)$".)

Another good example of a theory is the theory of groups. Here our language is $\{e, ^{-1}, *\}$ where $e$ is a constant symbol, $^{-1}$ is a unary function symbol, and $*$ is a binary function symbol; and one collection of closed formulas which generate our theory consists of the following:

- **Identity**: $\forall x(e*x=x*e=x)$.
- **Inverses**: $\forall x(x^{-1}*x=x*x^{-1}=e)$.
- **Associativity**: \forall x\forall y\forall z((x*y)*z=x*(y*z))$.

And finally, we can have another stupid theory! Our language $\{c, d\}$ has two constant symbols, and our theory is generated by the following two sentences:

- $\neg c=d$.
- $c=d$.

There's no rule saying that a theory has to be *consistent*! It's a good exercise to show that this theory is exactly the set of *all sentences* - that is, [a contradiction lets you prove everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Comment: My understanding of the definition of "theory" that gen quoted is that it has to be "closed under entailment" - so e.g. any theory must include all logical tautologies.  Of course, you can talk about "the theory generated by a set of axioms" where you're giving some useful examples of generating sets for theories.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Whoops! Missed that. Fixed.